# Suma de vectores en java

Tags: java

Con el algoritmo recursivo, ¿Como se hace un programa de suma de vectores en java?

```
int suma_vec(int v [], int n) {
    if (n == 0) {
        return v[n];
    } else {
        return suma_vec(v, n - 1) + v[n];
    } 
}
```

Comment: Cuál es tu pregunta amiga, pesuto que el algoritmo recursivo lo haz puesto ahí.

Comment: Creo que es apropiado que explique que tipo de suma desea que haga su programa, ya que a simple vista parece que ese algoritmo da error de IndexOutOf Bounds en ciertos casos

Answer (score 2):

Si quieres sumar recursivamente el contenido de un arreglo cuyos elementos son, por ejemplo, enteros:

```
int[] vec = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}

int suma_arreglo(a, i){
    if (i < a.length-1)
        acum = a[i] + suma_arreglo(a, i+1);
    else{
        acum = a[i];
        }
    return acum;
    }

System.out.print(suma_arreglo(vec, 0));
```

Lo probé con Python y transcribí en Java.

Comment: Walter, bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español. Por favor toma el [recorrido del sitio](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para conocer mas acerca del sitio. Saludos

Comment: Gracias, lo conozco y ha sido un referente desde hace años. Gracias Mauricio.

Answer (score 0):

Para sumar un Arreglo de enteros de manera recursiva en Java puedes seguir el siguiente ejemplo

```
int sum (int[] v, int idx){
    if(idx < 0 || idx >= v.length)
        throw new ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException();
    return idx == 0 ? v[0] : v[idx] + sum(v , idx - 1) ;
}

int sum(int[] v){
    return sum(v, v.length - 1);
}
```

Agregamos una `RuntimeException` para los indices fuera de rango y utilizamos una construcción mas compacta.
Utilizarlo es muy sencillo

```
int [] v = new int[]{1,2,3,4,5};
sum(v) // Prints 15!
```